# What's the origin of "Gravity-Defying Sweatdrops?"

Tags: manga-production

In lots of manga, when people are nervous, sweatdrops are drawn. But when they're EXTREMELY nervous, **sweatdrops fly upwards** instead (against gravity).

**Anyone know where this visual symbol originates from, and how it came to be?**

World Trigger Chapter 2 Page 12

[image: World Trigger Chapter 2 Page 12]

Comment: A good example would help tremendously, because I have no idea what you've described is anything I've seen in manga or anime. What manga is that Yuno from? And did you mean the sweatdrops on the face are drawn to flow upward or actually flying off the face towards the sky?

Comment: @Gao I updated the question to have a better example.